# Kollar-Matsusaka's finiteness theorem from a topological perspective

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

I am looking to find a reference or proof for the following topological version of Kollar-Matsusaka's theorem, which does not seem to be stated explicitly in the literature.

First I recall the definition of Hilbert polynomial, let $X$ be a complex manifold, $\alpha$ an ample line bundle on $X$. Define $H(X,\alpha)(t) =  \chi(X,t\alpha)$. By the Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch theorem is a  polynomial in $t$ with degree $n = \dim(X)$.

**Statement:** Fix a polynomial $P(t)$ with $\deg(P(t)) =n$. Then the class $\mathcal{C}_{p}$ of smooth projective $n$-folds polarised by an ample line bundle $\alpha$ with Hilbert polynomial equal to $P(t)$, contains finitely many underlying smooth manifolds up to diffeomorphism.

After looking at the orginal papers of Kollar and Matsusaka, I cannot find this statement. Although it seems to be used implicitly by several others when discussing the classification of Fano varieties, and in other areas.
(By the way, I am not sure of the exact attribution of this result, perhaps it should be attributed to one of these author's individually. I am not sure which exact paper it follows from. Please correct me if this is wrong).

Comment: The Kollar--Matsusaka theorem implies (by the theory of Hilbert schemes/Chow varieties) that there is a smooth (projective) morphism of varieties $f_P:X_P \to Y_P$ such that each variety in the class $C_p$ is isomorphic to one of the fibres. The diffeomorphism type of a fibre is constant on the connected components of  $Y_P$ by Ehresmann's theorem (by stratifying $Y_P$ you can assume all connected components are smooth), so since $Y_P$ has only finitely many connected components the statement follows.

Comment: If $c_1(X)=0$, your "Hilbert polynomial" is constant.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this definition was wrong of course. I think the statement should be correct now.

Comment: Yes, it is (except that of course $X$ should be compact). And ulrich's comment gives the answer.